# Parameters for cv.stereoCalibrate() to calculate R and T with undistorted images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, calibration

i'm trying to calibrate two different cameras and get the extrinsics. I've used `cv.cameraCalibrate()` to get the intrinsics of both cameras and i want to use

`cv.stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, imageSize)`

to get the `R` and `T` Matrix. But now i am unsure about the parameters to this function since i've undistorted my images before finding the chessboard. What values should i set the `cameraMatrixes` and the `distCoeffs` to?

I've tried to set them as the previously calculated matrixes, but that gives completely wrong results. If i set them to `None` they are in the right ballpark, but not quite right. Now i am unsure what's right or wrong and if i've made a mistake beforehand.

Also, can i set the `imageSize` to `None`, since the flag `CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` is enabled? If i understood the documentation correctly, then the `imageSize` isn't need, because i don't want to calculate the intrinsics.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: could you add your code & possibly the images?

Comment: Hey, the actual code is quite big, because i had to preprocess the images quite a bit (One camera is a low resolution thermal camera, the other being a Realsense D435). What parts of the code do you need?

Comment: ok so, docs on the APIs suck (and so do the APIs), have sucked since forever, and to understand how to use those APIs sensibly, you'll need the books that are the basis for all this dark magic. "multi view geometry" is probably the one you want, but others (szeliski) should be good too. -- it is my understanding that stereoCalibrate calculates all the intrinsics, but you can give it those guesses as initial values to the optimization (or you can nail some stuff down with flags). it is also my understanding that those points need to be un-undistorted, i.e. straight from the camera's picture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to use the raw images and see if that is better. Also thank you for the book recommendations. I will look into it.